# finding maximum depth of chapter

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, max, depth, xpath-2.0

everyone . In this case ,I want to conpute the maxximun depth of the chapter.For instance, a book without chapters has height 0 . A book only has chapters with no sections ,the height should be 1.The folowing is xml:

```
<book title="D">
<author>
  <name>abc</name>
</author>

<chapter title="chapter1">
  <section title="section1.1"/>
  <section title="section1.2">
    <section title="section1.2.1"/>
<section title="section1.2.2"/>
  </section>
  <section title="section1.3">
<section title="section1.3.1"/>
  </section>
</chapter>

<chapter title="chapter2"/>

</book>
```

By the way ,I used saxon. I want to try to use matching templates only.In this case ,the output is text ,and the result is

```
 3
```

This is my XSL for computing each note's depth? Is it right?And then how can out put the maximum of the curren by call a template named max??

```
<xsl:transform version="2.0"
           xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="book"/>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="book">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="chapter">
        <xsl:with-param name ="depth" select ="1"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="chapter|section">
    <xsl:param name="depth"  as="item()*"/>
    <xsl:variable name ="current" select ="$depth"/>
    <xsl:sequence select ="$depth"/>
    <xsl:if test ="not(empty(section))">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="section">
            <xsl:with-param name="depth" select="$depth+1"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>

    </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform >
```

Comment: Oh ,who can help me??Please...

Comment: I don't understand what is the *exact* output you want produced. Please, specify.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, short and easy one-liner XPath 2.0 solution. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**And here is your solution -- corrected**:

```
<xsl:transform version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:variable name="vDepths" as="xs:integer*">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="book"/>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:sequence select="max($vDepths)"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="book" as="xs:integer*">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="chapter">
   <xsl:with-param name ="depth" select ="1"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="chapter|section" as="xs:integer*">
  <xsl:param name="depth"  as="xs:integer"/>
  <xsl:variable name ="current" select ="$depth"/>

  <xsl:sequence select ="$depth"/>
  <xsl:if test ="not(empty(section))">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="section">
    <xsl:with-param name="depth" select="$depth+1"/>
   </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform >
```

Answer (score 2):

**XSLT 1.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="//*[self::chapter or self::section]">
       <xsl:sort data-type="number" order="descending" select=
        "count(ancestor::*[self::chapter or self::section])
        "/>
     </xsl:apply-templates>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="chapter|section">
    <xsl:if test="position()=1">
     <xsl:value-of select=
     "count(ancestor::*[self::chapter or self::section]) +1
     "/>
    </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<book title="D">
    <author>
        <name>abc</name>
    </author>
    <chapter title="chapter1">
        <section title="section1.1"/>
        <section title="section1.2">
            <section title="section1.2.1"/>
            <section title="section1.2.2"/></section>
        <section title="section1.3">
            <section title="section1.3.1"/></section>
    </chapter>
    <chapter title="chapter2"/>
</book>
```

**the wanted, correct answer is produced:**

```
3
```

Comment: Thank you.Now ,I think you've know the question?

Comment: @ZAWD: I have provided two different solutions that completely solve your problem. Please, consider accepting and upvoting.

Answer (score 0):

**Use**:

```
max(//(chapter|section)/count(ancestor::*[self::chapter or self::section]))+1
```

**This can be made slightly more efficient**:

```
max(//(chapter|section)[not(chapter or section)]
            /count(ancestor::*[self::chapter or self::section])
    ) +1
```

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev:Thank you.Now ,I think you've know the question?Is there something wrong in my xsl if I want to output the each note's depth of chapter?I mean ,for example,chapter1->"1",section1.1->"2",section1.2->"2",section1.2.1->"3" ......so the output of my xsl is 1 2 2 3 3 2 3 1.And now ,what I want is combining the template mach  and max template(which can seclect the maximum number of this sequence "1 2 2 3 3 2 3 1")

Comment: @ZAWD: I provided the correction to your solution in a separate answer.

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev:Yeah,you really gave me  a very good answer.But I don't want to use <xsl:sequence select="max($vDepths)"/>,just using a template named max(or something else.),call it to find the maximum.dose it will work?

Comment: @ZAWD: I have given you an XSLT 1.0 solution which uses only templates. You can use the same solution in XSLT 2.0.

Comment: @ZAWD: I also corrected *your* solution in a separate answer. Did you find it?

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev:Yes ,I did.Thanks for your kindess!!